# Application crashing on IPAD Air only

Tags: ios, ipad, webview, air, crash

I have a application which is crashing when i try to load the HTML file which is saved in the documents directory in the web view.
The application is crashing only on IPAD air and not on other devices.

This problem occurs only when I create an .ipa file and then open the HTML file . If I run the application from XCode then the HTML is loaded and the application does not crash.

When I checked the crash log , it shows

Exception Type :EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception SubType : KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010.

Please Help as I have been stuck with the issue for the past 3 days.

Comment: You'll need to post more information, enable the exception break point and post de code where this issue arises.

Comment: Almost certainly accessing data using a NULL pointer as the crash is 10 bytes from 0x0. As @rckoenes says, you need to use the debugger to identify the stack trace and post what you find. Otherwise could be anything.

Comment: How to identify the stack trace when i have installed the application on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in iPad air only when the webview opens PopOver pickers. After searching, the issue sometimes happens because of some kind of race or the sourceView in the following code is nil, so I have override this method and it works `-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{

//If sourceView is nil, do nothing

 if (viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController && !viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController.sourceView) {
    return;
  }

// to solve the race issue

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_USEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{
                   [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
               });

  }
```